# Rails 4 engine nested module not being included with uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a nested module set up as a base helper method which is not getting included in the app that uses the engine.

in lib/mol/blog/blog.rb

```
require "mol/blog/engine"

module Mol
  module Blog
    module Categories
      def self.included(base)
        base.helper_method :categories
      end

      def categories
        Mol::Cms::Category.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the engine's spec/dummy application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include Mol::Blog::Categories
end
```

This works fine and the categories appear as expected. However, when I try to use the engine in a different app, the Categories module is not being included.

in the app's application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include Mol::Blog::Categories
end
```

In the rails console, the error is `uninitialized constant Mol::Blog::Category (NameError)`

`Mol::Blog` is defined, no error or anything. Why is the Categories module not being recognised?

Comment: Are you sure the error is `uninitialized constant Mol::Blog::Category (NameError)`?. Isn't it `uninitialized constant Mol::Blog::Categories (NameError)`

Comment: yes, it is uninitialized constant Mol::Blog::Categories (NameError), sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not know about `Mol::Blog::Categories` module. You should require it in the `"mol/blog/engine.rb"` file or in the `"mol/blog.rb"` file.

```
# mol/blog.rb

require "mol/blog/categories"    

module Mol
  module Blog
   # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx, but I had already tried that and it made no difference. I'm wondering if since the gem is called mol-blog its looking for a path of mol-blog/ instead of mol/blog